# How to scrape text from <div class>, with <b> inside, using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beatifulsoup.

I tried to get texts in "Recommended:..." part from this website
[wongnai.com](https://www.wongnai.com/businesses?originalQ=sushi&mode=2&domain=1&page.number=1&cregion=8828&locale=en&categories=30&rerank=false&regions=1):

```
<div class="sc-1d7kslo-11 cWzosZ"><b>Recommended: </b>...</div>
```

I tried this one, but it didn't work

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"sc-1d7kslo-11 cWzosZ"})
```

The result didn't show any error or anything. I use Google Colab.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find_all()` will return a list of elements. You'll have to iterate through that list, and use `.text` to get the text (provided that the site isn't dynamic and what you are after is within the html source.

```
alpha = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"sc-1d7kslo-11 cWzosZ"})

for element in alpha:
    print (element.text)
```